# How to make Spring ignore an @autowired jmsTemplate field for test purposes?

Tags: java, spring, jms, autowired

I created a class that puts email requests into JMS queue using JMSTemplate.

The problem is that when I run unit tests, it throws an exception because it cannot create Sender bean because of the problem with autowiring JMSTemplate bean which is being provided by JBoss Application Server. Of course, it can't autowire it. JBoss is not running when doing unit testing.

So I have created two spring context configurations: one for production scope and one for test scope. In test context configuration I have removed the component scan from a package that holds the Sender class. It didn't work because Sender class is being used in some other places so I got rid of the JMSTemplate problem and substituted it with another bean creation error.

The Sender bean must be created.
Is there any way Spring could ignore a single autowired field for test purposes?
I'm planning on testing Sender features during integration testing.

I don't think that any code is necessary in this case.
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding JMS integration testing with Spring SingleConnectionFactory and CachingConnectionFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323560/understanding-jms-integration-testing-with-spring-singleconnectionfactory-and-ca)

Comment: @moghaddam I am not aware of something or that doesn't really answer my question at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I managed to solve it myself by using:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
```

on conflicting autowired fields.
I hope it helps someone.

However, it might not be the best idea ever to allow unit testing influence changes on production code so wiring up a dummy *JmsTemplate* during testing is probably the desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using javabased container configuration you can proxy the bean in the test configuration. We had a similar issue, where we ended up with a solution where we ignore the bean in question from the ComponentScan in the test context configuration, and create a simple proxy instead

Configuration sample ignoring the bean:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( // ...
    excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = IgnoredInterface.class)
        }
```

Proxy bean creation sample:

```
@Bean 
public IgnoredInterface ignoredInterface() {
    return (IgnoredInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        IgnoredInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] { IgnoredInterface.class },
        new MyInvocationHandler();
```

`MyInvocationHandler` is a simple implementation of `InvocationHandler` that just casts an `UnsupportedOperationException`